# Issues with text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: ellipsis, css

I have a problem with text-overflow: ellipsis - it doesn't want to work with my site. I am currently learning and I have this project in which I have div's with text with fixed height. I tried with text-overflow: ellipsis but I don't seem to be able to make it work. Now my code goes as follows:

```
<section class="comments">
    <p>
        Here is a short comment. 
    </p>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.comments p {
    height: 40px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-overflow: ellipsis-word;
    line-height: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It should work but it doesn't. I have tried to open it with Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE9 and it works for none of them. I tried to put a style in the `<p>` that contains the text, but it didn't help. I tried to change the `<p>` to `<div>`, and then tried to put a  style to the `<div>` but it didn't work. I tried with text-overflow: ellipsis only - it didn't work. I tried with text-overflow: clip - it didn't work. Obviously I am making a mistake somewhere but I guess it is too obvious for me to see it. Help!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html says, "This property only makes sense when a box has `white-space: nowrap` and an `overflow` other than `visible`."

Note that `text-overflow` is not in the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/).

Also, `ellipsis-word` does not appear to be implemented.  This style works for me (Win/Firefox and Chrome):

```
.comments p {
    height: 60px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```