# Ellipsis in css ("...") is not displaying

Tags: html, css

Css for child div like below

```
  width: 65%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 29px;
  max-height: 89px;
  min-height: 89px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

So when I have text out side div text is getting clip but can't see ellipsis (i.e "...")

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parekhurvish/o411kdbg/)

I want Ellipsis so that "..." come in last line if text is outside div

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues with text-overflow: ellipsis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619489/issues-with-text-overflow-ellipsis)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the main rule:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o411kdbg/1/**

---

**Multiple Lines**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 3em 2em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #cf6824;
  background: #f7f5eb;
}

p {
  display: block;
  /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 109.2px;
  /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>Pages that you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files that you download or bookmarks that you create will be kept.</p>
```

Comment: white-space: nowrap; 
adding this makes multiple line in single line

Comment: want multiple line with ellipsis

Comment: it is very browser specific

Comment: @Urvish Yeah, trying to find something which works out of chrome. I need time. Or browsers need time. Are you okay with JS Solution?

Comment: you can talk more time, I cannot use JS

Comment: @Urvish I don't need more time. Check this out: https://github.com/ericdrowell/Pure-CSS-Multiline-Ellipsis